# Update table by Preference and reorder table accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this app when you drag and drop rows in a list it reorders and SETS that row by preference number, 1-5 for example, 1 being most priority. So if I have 5 records in the list, I can then drag each row and when dropped it will reorder the list by preference.  I can move row 5 to row 1, or row 2 to row 3, etc...  This will update the preference number in the SQL table according where you drop.

This app is in real-time.  When new rows are added to the table automatically, they have an initial preference of "0".  This query will add the next number preference to the record, so if I have rows with preferences of 1-5, a new record comes in, then it's assigned a preference of 6:

```
with CTE as (
    select Id, Preference, cp.maxpref, row_number() over(order by Id) rn
    from [RadioQDB].[dbo].[Rad5]
    cross apply (
        select max(preference) maxpref
        from [RadioQDB].[dbo].[Rad5] p
    ) cp
    where preference = 0
)
update cte
set preference = maxpref + rn
where preference = 0
```

The issue I am having now is if a record is removed from the list during an update (not user drag and drop), let's say you have 1,2,3,4,5 records in the list.  If during the table update, a record is removed automatically, let's say #2, then you end up with preferences 1,3,4,5.  How can I move up everything and reorder the table accordingly by preference?
1 stays the same, 3 moves to 2, 4 moves to 3 and so forth.

Thank you.

Comment: Why bother? It still orders correctly with a gap in the sequence. Otherwise use `row_number`

Comment: The new record that comes in must be at the end of the list.  And the other list items need to be re-ordered accordingly because these are Cat Scans that were placed by physicians and they set the exact order of when they need to be completed for each patient. I'll try row_number again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a new record with `Preference=Max(Preference)+1` use the following query:

```
insert into Rad5 values(10,(select max(Preference)+1 from Rad5));
-- inserts a new record with id=10
```

To reorder the records according to the `Preference` after deleting a record try the following:

```
with cte as (
select id, Preference, row_number() over (order by Preference) as rn
from Rad5)
update cte set Preference=rn;
```

You can use `Trigger` on delete from your table to call the update query automatically whenever a record is deleted, if you want to do so use the following:

```
create trigger Rad5_Delete on Rad5
for delete 
as
with cte as (
select id, Preference, row_number() over (order by Preference) as rn
from Rad5)
update cte set Preference=rn;
```

See a demo from ***[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f244b6d81a387230837a145e6a9d789)***.